# Any suggestions on keeping my cat out of my bedroom, rather than closing my bedroom door?

Tags: cats, behavior, training

I have a lot of plants in my bedroom and I don't want my cat to damage the foliage. What can I do to let my cat know that my bedroom is off limits? Rather than just closing my bedroom door all the time.

Comment: Years of active observation and training that "this is not part of your territory", just as you train them to stay off kitchen counters... and then periodically confirm that the rule is still in force. Frankly, even if that's your goal it's easier to start with the door closed until the cat has learned where the lines are and decided that going past those lines is scary. And even then, if something the cat really wants is visible -- like yourself -- it's going to be an ongoing struggle. Closed door is a heckuva lot easier and more reliable. Lead cat not into temptation...

Comment: @Keshlam Please refrain from using comments as answers.

Comment: If you intended to say "I think that's complete enough to be an Answer" -- I'll consider it. If you intended to say what you wrote, you're asking me not to bother posting at all unless I feel I have something I consider a strong answer, which I think is a counterproductive suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did with my cat was that at first anytime the cat would enter my room I would just make the environment annoying to her, like some music or just dont let her nap in the room... I guess that knowing she would be annoyed if she entered my room she stopped trying to get into it, now I can keep my door open with no one inside of it and the cat still won't enter it.